# Numpy array not displaying color dimension of greyscale image after converting from PIL image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an RGB image to a greyscale image, then to a numpy array using the following code snippet:

```
img = Image.open("image1.png")
img = img.convert('L')
img = np.array(img, dtype='f')
print(img.shape)
```

The result is a numpy array of shape (128, 128). Is there anyway that I could convert a greyscale image to a numpy array so that it would have the color channel as well, i.e. the shape would be (128, 128, 1)?

Comment: You can do `img = img[..., np.newaxis]` to get that shape but I don't see how that gives you colour.

Comment: To expand on Mark's comment, this is a somewhat confusing question because the values of the `(128, 128)` array are the "colors" here. Sometimes you need to have a singleton dimension, but it's usually because you are using numpy broadcasting or something similar. Adding a singleton dimension changes nothing about the underlying data. So you have a good answer now from @crazycoder, but I am not sure you have a solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Mark mentioned in comments, add a dimension to the end if your array using newaxis:

```
img=img[...,None]
```

`None` will do similar as `np.newaxis`. It does not create a color, but adds a dimension similar to a single channel image.